# Session Overlap in Struts2

Tags: java, session, struts2, token

We are facing an issue regarding session overlap in our application. While checking the logs, it seems that the

**`session tracker that keeps the session id and page tracker that holds the session id value as well mismatches sometimes`**.

This particularly happens when more than one user are using the application and are accessing the same page albeit they have logged in separately in their own systems. We have asked the users whether they've opened multiple tabs while using the application but they've denied that they don't use multiple tabs or multiple browsers. 
Any help would surely be appreciated as we're getting hammered from management.
Thanks

Comment: Same questions I asked last time.

Comment: Hi, could you give me a link for your question? Were you able to solve it?

Comment: It was your question, with my requests for additional information.

Comment: This is the first time I'm posting here, Dave. Anyways, further information that I can provide is, the token values held in session becomes null and sometimes the session tracker id and page tracker id becomes null. We are using TokenInterceptor from Struts 2.0.

Comment: Then your co-worker is posting the same question, and I have the same questions I had on the original. No idea what a "page tracker ID" is. It's impossible to help at all with the information provided.